# HTML Search Function

Tags: html, search

I need a search function for on an intranet , can I do this purely in HTML ? and if so could you possibly point me in the right direction , I tried googeling it but it came up with searching via search engines.

Cheers

EDIT: I only need it to search for text on 1 page , its not a whole website , just one page.

Comment: HTML is purely a mark-up language, meaning it is only used for visual interface design.  You cannot do any kind of manipulation on input from the user with pure HTML, although with Javascript and HTML more possibilities are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **will** need some server-side scripting in order to provide the directory listings.

I recommend using PHP's `glob` function recursively, but there might be a better option.

Edit:

For one page, using JavaScript, you could get the contents of all of the elements, and use [regex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) or `indexOf` to determine if the string exists within the text, and if so, *where*.

If you are to use the `indexOf` function, as the function only returns the index of the **first** occurrence of the string, you will need to repeat the search until you've gathered all occurrences.

You may specify the `start` parameter to snip the front of the searching area, to begin the new search *after* your last found occurrence.